# Changing color of fontAwesome icons with visNetwork

Tags: r, font-awesome, vis.js, visnetwork

I tried the example proposed in the [documentation](https://datastorm-open.github.io/visNetwork/image_icon.html) of visNetwork R package regarding the usage of fontAwesome icons.

In the example below I use the option of passing the node properties via a data.frame. However, the color of the icons in the output gets a default blue color.

```r
library(visNetwork)

nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, 
                    shape = "icon", 
                    icon.face = "FontAwesome",
                    color = c("#800000", "#0000ff", "#ffa500"), # doesn't have any effect on icon color
                    icon.code = c("f1ad", "f015", "f007"))
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(2,3))

visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  addFontAwesome()
```

[image: node-no-color-effect]

It seems that the alternative is to use the grouping option described in the documentation. However, I would want to have the data.frame option working as well and I can't figure out at the moment what I do wrong above.

```r
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, 
                    shape = "icon", 
                    group = c("A", "B", "C"))
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(2,3))

visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  visGroups(groupname = "A", shape = "icon", 
            icon = list(code = "f1ad", color = "#800000")) %>%
  visGroups(groupname = "B", shape = "icon", 
            icon = list(code = "f015", color = "#0000ff")) %>%
  visGroups(groupname = "C", shape = "icon", 
            icon = list(code = "f007", color = "#ffa500")) %>%
  addFontAwesome()
```

[image: alternative]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `color` to `icon.color` and everything works:

```
library(visNetwork)

nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, 
                    shape = "icon", 
                    icon.face = "FontAwesome",
                    icon.color = c("#800000", "#0000ff", "#ffa500"), # doesn't have any effect on icon color
                    icon.code = c("f1ad", "f015", "f007"))
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(2,3))

visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  addFontAwesome()
```

[image: Coloured visNetwork]